# Assigning a Group to a user at signup - Django allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Trying to change the authorization of my website from the main Django auth to allauth. I've made a custom SignupForm based on the standard SignupForm in allauth. I've added a choicefield based on the pre-added Group objects in the database. Now I am trying to assign the user to the Group based on the choice he/she makes in the signupform.  I am overwriting the signup method to add the user's choice to the user in the database. The user gets registered but is not assigned to any group at all. I'm stuck on how to solve this.

forms.py:

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    user_group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.exclude(name='admin').exclude(name='personeel'),
                                        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                        initial=('particulier')
                                        )
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')

    fields = ('user_group', )

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        role = self.cleaned_data['user_group']
        group = role or None
        g = Group.objects.get(name=group)
        user.groups.add(g)
        user.save()
        return user
```

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'users.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}
```

The first and last name are correctly assigned to the right fields in the user instance. The role variable in the signup method should return the chosen value of the choice field (either 'zakelijk' or 'particulier'). Then the g variable points this value to the group.name and the g value gets added.

Do I miss something here?

Comment: Is your custom signup method being called ?
SignupForm save method calls this custom signup.
Require some more additional details on this , is your first_name and last_name being set ?

Comment: Yes this is done correctly. First and last name are being set within the user instance

Answer (score 0):

Saving a new user from the signup form into the database is slightly different in Django Allauth then it is in the generic Django authentication system. Allauth uses a DefaultAccountAdapter to handle the logic.

To make the above question clear see my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160354/post-save-user-is-inactive-based-on-assigned-user-group-django-allauth).